# RestTemplate interceptor without access to RestTemplate

Tags: aspectj, resttemplate, spring-aop

I am writing a library where I want to inject a header on all outgoing API calls that are done using `RestTemplate`. 
The `RestTemplate` can be created by using the `new` operator or by autowiring in the applications where this library will be used - that is not under my control.
What is the best way to achieve this?

I know that we can implement `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and add it to the `RestTemplate`, but as said above, I don't have access to the `RestTemplate`.

I can think of using AOP for this by defining the pointcut for `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postFor*(..))`, and other methods, but how can I inject the header in this.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: When `new` operator is used to create a `RestTemplate` instance , it is not a container managed bean . Spring AOP can only advice Spring bean.

Comment: That's right. Any other approach/solution that you can think of?

Comment: with pure `aspectj` it might be possible. I do not have much expertise in that and would suggest you to add `aspectj` tag to your question to get the right attention.

Comment: You may also provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for non-spring aspectj experts to help you out.

Comment: If you indeed add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to this question, as R.G said, I am sure I can help with AspectJ.